# Интернет-магазин на чистом PHP для портфолио PHP-разработчика

Tags: php, mysql, интернет-магазин

Решил написать интернет-магазин в качестве проекта для портфолио. Так как, по сути, это моя первая крупная программа (не только на PHP), хотел бы обсудить её реализацию. Узнать, что об этом думают разбирающиеся в сфере люди

В базе данных содержатся таблицы:

- **users** с данными о пользователях: id (Primary, Auto Increment), логин, пароль через password_hash(), email, расширение аватарки (имя файла совпадает с логином), ФИО, дата рождения, город, ранг (постоянный клиент, VIP и т.д.)
- **products** с данными о товарах: id товара, id категории, имя производителя, цена, количество товара на складе, оценка покупателей
- **categories** с данными о категориях товаров: id категории, id родительской категории, краткое описание
- **orders** с данными о заказах: id заказа, номер заказа, id покупателя, сумма, состояние заказа, способ оплаты, способ доставки
- **ordered_products** c заказанными товарами (т.к. в заказе может быть несколько товаров, создаю под них отдельную таблицу): id заказа, id товара, цена (с учётом скидки)
- **images** с фотографиями товаров: id, id товара, путь к файлу

При заходе пользователя на сайт открывается главная страница, на которую подгружается несколько товаров из базы данных в зависимости от оценки. При нажатии на кнопку "Аккаунт" открывается страница пользователя с его данными и отдельной вкладкой (кнопкой) под открытие списка заказов. В список заказов выводятся , сформированные из таблицы БД **orders** (WHERE ID = user_id)

При заходе администратора на свой аккаунт открывается две вкладки: список заказов (с выборкой по дате), и интерфейс для создания новых товаров, категорий на сайте.

Осталось ещё несколько функций сайта, которые я пока не знаю как реализовать.

1. Где хранить комментарии и отзывы к товару в базе? Держать их вперемешку в таблице **comments**? Не будет ли в таком случае поиск среди всех комментариях слишком долгим?
2. Как реализовать смену языка? Придётся прописывать отдельно новый сайт с английским языком и английской базой?
3. Как ограничить пользователя одним отзывом на товар? Перед отправкой каждого отзыва проводить поиск по таблице отзывов этого товара?

Понимаю, что важно как можно больше продумать самостоятельно, но всё-таки хотелось бы снизить число ударов граблями по лбу к минимуму. Буду рад любым советам, не только касающимся указанных выше вопросов

Comment: Я не знаток, но, учитывая, что поппулярный интернет-магазин обязан хранить и обрабатывать огромное количество данных, предположу, что не очень скажется на быстродействии добавление к свойствам пользователя (имя, пароль и проч.) строки, в которой указываются id товаров, под которыми покупатель уже оставлял комментарий (например, это может выглядеть так: `1_2_3_4`). Надеюсь, где-нибудь явно не указано, что это плохой вариант.

Comment: Для локализации пользуются не базой, а специальными файлами с локализованной информацией. например в папке `localization` где есть папки `ru`, `en`, `de` и т.д. в которых есть файлы, отвечающие за локализацию в формате "ключ" -> "значение", где ключом как правило выступает английское слова а значение - зависит от языка перевода. В ядре есть специанльный класс,который по специальной логике подставляет значения в код, по ключу. А в коде на клиенте написано везде, где надо что-то локализовывать примерно так:`Yii::t('app', 'Hello, {username}!')`. Где `Yii::t` - класс и метод? `app` - что переводим

Comment: как пример, посомтрите фреймворк `yii2` и его возможность интернационализации

Comment: Я думаю, что начать лучше с выбора шаблона проектирования, если конечно, вы не будете создавать свой собственный. Еще нужно более менее определится с бизнес логикой. Тогда можно уже и проектировать БД.

Comment: "Не будет ли в таком случае поиск среди всех комментариях слишком долгим?" - сдается мне, что поиск с гораздо большей вероятностью будет долгим при неправильно составленном запросе. Так что мой ответ - храните все комментарии в таблице comments.

Comment: Для запрета написания более одного отзыва на товар очевидно необходимо проверять наличие отзыва в базе. И если отзыв существует - то на фронте не показывать форму добавления, на бэке - не сохранять избыточный отзыв, выдавая предупреждение.

Comment: вам бы не про портфолио думать надо, а учебники по БД почитать для начала.

Comment: В современных условиях писать что-то большое с нуля на чистом php - это всё равно, что уйти в тайгу, молиться двумя перстами и самому хлеб выращивать и охотой мясо добывать.
Если Вы хотите сделать хороший, "продающий" портфолио - ни в коем случае не показывайте никому эту поделку, даже если Вы её сделаете.
В хорошем портфолио должны быть несколько примеров (раз уж хотите магазин сделать) на современных фреймворках и на современных CMS'ках. Сделайте один магазин на shop-script, один на какой-нибудь drupal и один на laravel плюс один на Yii2. Времени займёт столько же, но покажет людям Уровень

Comment: Это всё равно что пойти устраиваться водителем, и начать рассказывать, как ты хорошо умеешь сам колёса перебортировать, двигатель перебирать и подвеску перетряхивать. А ещё умеешь работать на токарном станке и поэтому любой подшипник починить можешь.
В общем, на мой взгляд человека, работающего мидлом php, бредовая идея.

Comment: @RomanBush вот так и появляется целый пласт разработчиков, которые чуть влево от концепции конструктора (фреймворка) и знаний нет никаких больше.

Comment: я не к тому, что не надо знать фреймворки, но надо знать вообще как мир устроен, прежде чем вообще начинать что-либо программировать на каком-либо языке.

Comment: 100% ты не напишешь этот магазин, такие вещи не пишутся "для портфолио". Ты застрянешь на одной только интернационализации. Но один совет дам. в таблице юзерс логин - это лишнее, авторизрваться надо по телефону/email; расширение аватарки - лишнее (имя файла совпадает с айди, картинку перекодируем в единый формат). Но в целом да - если возникают вопросы "ой, поиск товара или юзера по айди в таблице коммнтариев это долго наверное будет" - то тебе гостевую бы книгу написать уже будет огромным достижением

Comment: @teran Это бессмысленное замечание. Сейчас никому не нужны строители-каменщики, которые умеют сам кирпичи обжигать. Наоборот, нужны те, кто умеют и успешно осваивают новые технологии. И помогают на их основе придумывать ещё более новые.

Comment: @RomanBush интересно, как вы будете делать новую технологию на языке PHP не умея на нём создавать, т.к. пользуетесь готовыми технологиями, которые не идеальны ИЗНУТРИ и нужно вдаваться в детали, глубь и копот, чтобы понять что там не так? *задумался*

Comment: @СергейМишин "Вдаваться вглубь и под капот" - вещи слабо связанные с портфолио. Посмотрите первое предложение вопроса. Я таки настаиваю, что демонстрировать знание современных технологий более важный навык для портфолио, чем умение "заглядывать под капот" и писать велосипед с нуля.

Comment: @RomanBush а мой ответ был не к портфолио, а к комментарию про "создавать новые технологии".  А знание технологии без знаний работы языка в итоге штампуют мартышек, которые не способны думать и могут что по шаблонам с интернета делать шаблонные сайты, не больше визитки или магазин на 100 человек (потому что в высоконагруженность же не погружался). И таким "разработчикам" грош цена. Потому что в разработке нужно **думать**, но если цель - тупая штамповка визиток 100 раз в месяц - то да, знание современных технологий важнее (которая будет в итоге во всём поверхностная, что тоже так себе).

Comment: @СергейМишин Ну и получается, что в данный момент Вы просто занимаетесь флудом. Потому что все мои камменты были по поводу портфолио. А Вы зачем-то пытаетесь разводить философию на посторонние темы.

Comment: @RomanBush https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1130862/#comment1955397_1130862  - то есть это по поводу портфолио, а не ответ пользователю не ТС? Ну-ну, ну-ну.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интернет-магазин это не только товары и заказы, это обычный сайт, к которому прикручивается функционал магазина. Соответственно, в админке должен быть полный функционал по управлению сайтом. По поводу ваших вопросов:

1. Разделить таблицы, ведь комментарии я оставляю ко всему магазину.
2. Сделать можно по разному, но суть - в той же таблице, например, добавив языковых полей, типа title_ru, title_en
3. Да, ищем отзыв юзера к товару и скрываем форму для отзыва.
4. По поводу папки localization - годится только для статичных данных, типа названия месяцев, дней недель и т.д. Все остальное через БД.

По поводу всего остального - пишите, научитесь проектировать, столкнувшись с куууучей своих же грабель. А потом плюнете и будете работать с современными "свистоперделками", нужными для работодателей))

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую добавить
1. Таблицу с категориями товаров
2. Таблицу со свойствами товаров (привязывать к категориям)
Чтобы при добавлении товара ему можно было присвоить свойство, например Лампочка - "Тип" [светодиодная, накаливания и т. д.].